# скрыть/отобразить несколько блоков по клику

Tags: javascript, html

помогите разобраться со следующей проблемой.
Задача: при клике на кнопку отображать/скрывать множество текстовых блоков на странице.

Сделал следующим образом:

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#show').click(function(){
    $('#name').toggle();
    });
    });
```

```css
#name {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#" id="show">Скрыть / отобразить</a>

<div id="name">А</div>
<div id="name">Б</div>
<div id="name">В</div>
<div id="name">Г</div>
<div id="name">Д</div>
```

Но это работает только на первый элемент. Как сделать так, чтобы отображались/скрывались все элементы с одинаковым ID?

Comment: Одинаковый ID нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы не использовал один ID для разных элементов, лучше объединить их классом. Так как ID подразумевает что элемент уникальный. Но если надо использовать именно такую конструкцию то вот так будет работать:

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#show').click(function(){
    $('div#name').toggle();
    });
    });
```

```css
#name {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="show">Скрыть / отобразить</a>

<div id="name">А</div>
<div id="name">Б</div>
<div id="name">В</div>
<div id="name">Г</div>
<div id="name">Д</div>
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="show">Скрыть / отобразить</a>
<div id="all-blocks">
<div id="name">А</div>
<div id="name">Б</div>
<div id="name">В</div>
<div id="name">Г</div>
<div id="name">Д</div>
</div>
```

css :

```
#name {
        display: block;
}
```

js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#show').click(function(){
            $('#all-blocks').css("display", "none");
          });
    });
```